# Finding the depth of a tree given a parent array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tree

A parent array P is given where P[i] denotes the parent of the ith node in the tree(the tree is generic). Parent of root is indicated with -1. I need to find the height/depth of tree.

Example: P = {-1,0,1,6,6,0,0,2,7}. So P[1] = 0 means the parent of node 1 is 0 and so on.

My approach:

```
1. Sort P in O(nlogn). This gives P = {-1,0,0,0,1,2,6,6,7}
2. Scan through the array. 
   If a change is observed on going from index i to i+1 then increment depth (depth++).
   eg When going from index 3 to index 4 of sorted P, there is a change from 0 to 1. So increment depth.
   This scanning takes O(n) time
3. depth - 1 is the depth of the tree.
```

This approach seems to work on the examples I've tried but I'm not sure if I'm missing a case where it may fail. Could someone provide a counter example? Thanks

Comment: Hint for a different approach: See if you can make a function, depth(), that takes a single node index as a parameter and tells you the depth of that node.  It will use recursion, and require O(n^2) time if called in a loop for every node (which is necessary to determine the overall tree height).  Now how could that recursion be eliminated, and the total time for the loop reduced to O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect. Consider two arrays: {-1, 0, 0, 1, 1} and {-1, 0, 0, 1, 2}. The number of changes is different for them, but these two trees have the same height.